# How to set icon to wx.ComboBox in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to set search bitmap icon to wx.ComboBox but I am not found any property or function to set in wxpython.

Comment: You will have to be more specific about what, where and when, you want to see. A coded example of what you have tried so far and a description of what you want to achieve is customary. See https://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.BitmapComboBox.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.